# .Net Core ignoring Environment Variable DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE

Tags: c#, .net, linux, jenkins, .net-core

It seems [apparent that you can save some time doing .NET Core builds](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Stop-wasting-time-during-NET-Core-builds) by setting Environment variable `DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true`. I am finding this is not the case on CentOS 7 and Debian Jessie Linux distros.

I have a Jenkins slave Docker image, used by Jenkins to build .NET Core services, my image tag is `jenkins.slave.dotnet.image`.

The Jenkins Docker Plugin, uses `jenkins.slave.dotnet.image` to spin up a slave container when a build is triggered. The Jenkins Docker Plugin has access to a Docker host where the `jenkins.slave.dotnet.image` resides.

In the Dockerfile for my `jenkins.slave.dotnet.image` I set environment vars like so:

```
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE true
```

All works fine, except those environment variables are being ignored by `dotnet` commands, see the output of a Jenkins build for a .NET Core service, you should not see the circled text in the image if environment variable `DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true` is being checked by `dotnet` cmds:

[image]

Connecting (`docker exec -it jenkins.slave.dotnet.container bash`) to a container that uses the `jenkins.slave.dotnet.image` you can see that DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE is correctly set to "true":

[image]

Output of dotnet --info:

[image]

Here is my Dockerfile for my Jenkins Slave Docker image (`jenkins.slave.dotnet.image`) that my Jenkins master runs containers of to do .NET Core Builds (**this is the environment that `dotnet publish -c Debug -v m` is executed in**):

```
FROM tsl.devops.jenkins.slave.basic.docker.image
MAINTAINER Brian Ogden

#############################################
# .NET Core SDK
#############################################
RUN yum install -y \
    libunwind \
    libicu

RUN curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848821
RUN mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
RUN ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin

#add Trade Service Nuget Server
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.nuget/NuGet
COPY /files/NuGet.Config /home/jenkins/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

RUN chown -R jenkins /home/jenkins/.nuget
RUN chgrp -R jenkins /home/jenkins/.nuget

RUN chmod 600 /home/jenkins/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config
RUN chmod 700 /home/jenkins/.nuget/NuGet

#speed up dotnet core builds
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
ENV DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE true
#############################################
```

Here is an example of a .NET Core Micro Service build artifact that builds in the Jenkins Slave Docker environment I just shared above:

```
FROM tsl.devops.dotnetcore.base.image
MAINTAINER Brian Ogden

#############################################
# .NET Service setup
#############################################
ARG ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/TSL.Bom.Service/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT 

EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TSL.Bom.Service.dll"]
#############################################
```

Comment: 1) Which `dotnet` CLI command is causing it to build the NuGet sentinel cache? The source makes me think it shouldn't matter, but would help to start troubleshooting... 2) you mention CentOS specifically, are you implying it *only* happens in CentOS, or that you are just observing the behavior in CentOS?

Comment: Oh and what is the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: @vcsjones I updated my answer it was happening when my Docker Slave OS was Debian:Jessie as well. I doubt that my source would affect this...I guess it is possible but I do not see how at the moment. Regarding dotnet --info output I will post that tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @vcsjones I added output of dotnet --info to my question

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @svick I added my Dockerfiles

Comment: From the images you shared I take it you're using version 1.0.4 of the dotnet cli. Try upgrading to 1.1.0 or later (don't know if there's a later 1.x release). I took a look at the github history and saw that there have been some changes regarding the environment variables after 1.0.4. Maybe it's as simple as that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is replaced by `DOTNET_NOLOGO`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables) you can find more about `dotnet` environment variables, and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Cli/dotnet/Program.cs) is the source code of dotnet CLI on Github.

Comment: There is also `DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT` env variable - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#dotnet_cli_telemetry_optout